# ¿ingresar millones de caracteres de entrada en C?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos

mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo guardo caracteres de entrada en *C*, a partir de dos millones de caracteres en adelante, desde un `scanf`, `gets` o `cin`?.

Lo que pasa es que estuve investigando como hacerlo, pero el tipo de dato `char` solamente es dos bytes, pero almacena hasta 1 millón de caracteres. Si quiero poner un millon y medio de caracteres de entrada, ya no acepta algo como esto. Quiero lograr con millones de caracteres ya sea en *C* o en *C++*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 1500000 //con un millon si acepta caracteres desde el compilador de gcc de linux ya con millon y medio no

int main() {
char X[N];

scanf("%s", X);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cuando tu declaras un array tal que:

```
#define N 1500000
char X[N];
```

Estás consumiendo memoria de la pila del programa. La pila del programa es un recurso ciertamente escaso... unos pocos KB frente a los varios GB de memoria RAM de un equipo actual.

La pila no debe usarse para almacenar objetos de gran tamaño. Para eso tenemos a nuestra disposición la memoria dinámica:

```
char *X = malloc(N);
// ...
free(X);
```

Usando `malloc` podemos usar toda la memoria que el equipo sea capaz de proporcionarnos.

En el comentario de la otra respuesta has puesto lo siguiente:

> asigne mas memoria a una pila lo hará y bueno la **clase string** si acepta millones de caracteres obviamente sin espacios ...

Dos apuntes respecto a este comentario:

1. La clase `string` es **propia de C++**, no de C, En C no se pueden usar clases luego un código que use `std::string` no va a compilar **jamás** en C.
2. La clase `string` **sí admite espacios**. Otra cosa es que `cin` **no los lea**. Para leer con espacios hay que usar `std::getline()`.